Cancel/abort a delayed fetch request
I have a simple UI with a button to trigger a fetch request to an API.
<button type="button"id="fetch">Fetch products</button>

I want to implement some logic (using AbortController) so that any re-fetch cancels a previous ongoing request. To simulate network latency (and make sure my abort logic works fine), I have wrapped the fetch logic into a promise to delay the fetch operation. On every click event, I check whether a controller already exists to cancel its related request.
Note I do not want to disable the button or debounce user's click here.
Here is the base code:
const btnEl = document.querySelector('#fetch');
const API_BASE_URL =
  'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/fetching-data/can-store';

let controller;

const onClick = async () => {
  try {
    const products = await fetchProducts();
    console.log('Products:', products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch products.', error?.message ?? error);
  }
};

btnEl.addEventListener('click', () => onClick());

❌ Here is the business logic I initially tried. I expected the promise's executor function to close around the controller value of the outer scope. It is obviously not the case... It looks like the new fetch request mutates the previous abort controller before it has a chance to fire. I'm not sure why this does not work ...
function fetchProducts() {
  return fetchDataWithDelay(API_BASE_URL + '/products.json');
}

// Pretend data fetching is hitting the network.
function fetchDataWithDelay(url, delay = 3000) {
  if (!url) throw new Error('URL is required.');

  if (controller) {
    controller.abort('Fetch aborted by the user.');
    console.log('Fetch aborted.');
  }
  controller = new AbortController();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Fetching data with ${delay}ms delay...`);
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, { signal: controller.signal });
        response.ok
          ? resolve(await response.json())
          : reject(new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`));
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
}

Multiple clicks within the specified delay result in as many fetch requests. Here are the console logs I get after 2 click events within 3000ms:
Fetching data with 3000ms delay...
Fetch aborted.
Fetching data with 3000ms delay...
Products:
(12) [{...}, {...}, {...}, ..., {...}]
Products:
(12) [{...}, {...}, {...}, ..., {...}]

✅ I managed to make it work by extracting the abort controller related logic to the caller function:
function fetchProducts() {
 // Moved the controller logic here...
  if (controller) {
    controller.abort('Fetch aborted by the user.');
    console.log('Fetch aborted.');
  }
  controller = new AbortController();

 // ... and passed the controller as a function parameter to the delayed fetch function
  return fetchDataWithDelay(API_BASE_URL + '/products.json', controller);
}

function fetchDataWithDelay(url, abortController, delay = 3000) {
  if (!url) throw new Error('URL is required.');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Fetching data with ${delay}ms delay...`);
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, { signal: abortController.signal });
        response.ok
          ? resolve(await response.json())
          : reject(new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`));
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
}

Here I get the expected output after 2 click events within 3000ms:
Fetching data with 3000ms delay...
Fetch aborted.
Fetching data with 3000ms delay...
Failed to fetch products. Fetch aborted by the user.
Products:
(12) [{...}, {...}, {...}, ..., {...}]

But this time not entirely sure why this works (smells like closure...) 
Any insights will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time 

Your code would actually work if you didn't use setTimeout. Or if you had cancelled the timeout as well.

"But this time not entirely sure why this works (smells like closure...)" - yes, it's the closure over abortController. That variable doesn't change its value, compared to controller. Btw it would be even more appropriate to pass only the abort signal.

Totally agreed with you @Bergi about cancelling the timeout but I really wanted here to go with the abort controller way. Strangely I do need the setTimeout here to cancel a previous fetch (manually clicking the button on the UI) because the response is too quick (even with slow 3G throttling enabled). Thanks!

You still can use an abort signal with the timeout, see the post I've linked.

The problem is with your setTimeout(), in the working example you create a copy with the argument abortController so in the setTimeout's callback it's the proper intended valid controller.
When you don't use the function, when you click you override the controller before it's passed to fetch() ‍♂️ since the timeout hasn't happened yet.
So if you remove setTimeout() the first code would work ok.

@ddZ6ii if my answer solved your problem please consider to accept it (the gray checkbox) that's how stackoverflow works, thanks

Thanks @Alexander. For the "non-working" example, I thought the promise was immediately created (with only its inner code being delayed), so I was expecting the promise to close over the controller value at creation and  to "remember" it until it settles. It appears its value gets mutated by the next fetch request though. Does this mean the promise does not create a closure?  On the "working" example, the controller variable is passed by reference to the fetchDataWithDelay function, so I would expect the same behavior but here the closure seems to work... Maybe I am overly confused I'm sorry
